# MS graph update subscription (PATCH) not working

Tags: call, microsoft-teams, subscription, microsoft-graph-api

I have created a call record subscription and it works fine.

While updating the same subscription from java code using Google http client com.google.api.client.http.* , i am getting error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HTTP method PATCH not supported.

Does Microsoft support PATCH request using google client ?
Could anyone help ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you share more details like endpoint you are calling and request body?

Comment: Endpoint that i am calling - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}

RequestBody -
{
 
  "expirationDateTime": "2022-05-30T12:36:46.533Z"

}

PATCH request works fine from postman.
BUt when i did same from code , it gives above mentioned error.
POST works fine from code as well.

Comment: Could you please refer this? https://www.thejavaprogrammer.com/java-lang-illegalargumentexception/